# No sound on Lenovo X1 Extreme Gen 3

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, manjaro, thinkpad

I just installed Manjaro i3 on my Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 3, and, to my surprise, the thing that's not working is the audio and the sound.

The "status bar" icon shows a muted icon, and `alsamixer` doesn't show any levels on anything.
[image: i3 status bar]

Alsamixer:

[image: alsamixer]

I tried to search the internet, but I can't find anything. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Output of `lspci -nn` (maybe it's useful):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:9b54] (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller [8086:06f9]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:06ed]
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:06ef]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462/9560 [8086:06f0]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller [8086:06e0]
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:06e3]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:06b8] (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:06bf] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:06b0] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:068e]
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS [8086:06c8]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:06a3]
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:06a4]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] [10de:1f95] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
05:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
05:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
05:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
06:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15eb] (rev 06)
2c:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ec] (rev 06)
54:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Genesys Logic, Inc Device [17a0:9755]
55:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba Corporation Device [1179:011a]
```

Comment: 1. Install kernel 5.9.x 2. Install the latest alsa-sof-firmware (possibly from git)

If nothing helps, file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/

Answer (score 0):

Can be a challenge, if not done so already try using the following:

```
sudo pacman -S pulseaudio pulseaudio-alsa pavucontrol

reboot
```