# Intel sound card not working

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm having troubles getting my sound card working. Here is some information on it:

```
ignatius@catch22bbs:~$ lsmod|grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq                90112  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_usb_audio         376832  1
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            53248  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  2 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   188416  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_intel        49152  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               274432  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       40960  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    73728  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          348160  4 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          57344  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         184320  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          122880  6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               159744  10 snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   126976  17 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mc                     77824  8 videodev,au8522_decoder,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,dvb_core,videobuf2_common,au0828,tuner
usbcore               344064  9 xhci_hcd,snd_usb_audio,usbhid,snd_usbmidi_lib,usb_storage,btusb,xhci_pci,uas,au0828

ignatius@catch22bbs:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1348000 irq 168
 1 [HVR850         ]: USB-Audio - HVR-850
                      Hauppauge HVR-850 at usb-0000:00:14.0-8, high speed

ignatius@catch22bbs:~$ lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS

ignatius@catch22bbs:~$ inxi -Aa
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 1-8:4 chip-ID: 2040:7240 alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 class-ID: 0102 chip-ID: 8086:a3f0 serial: 4034577942
    class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Hauppauge WinTV HVR-850 type: USB driver: au0828,snd-usb-audio
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-5-amd64 running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

Thank you.

Comment: so that's information, but what is the problem, besides "not working", can you elaborate

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738379/intel-comet-lake-pch-lp-cavs-no-sound-on-debian-110-0-bullseye https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651149/intel-comet-lake-pch-lp-cavs-sound-card-can-not-configure-device-for-linux-kern https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620768/no-sound-on-lenovo-x1-extreme-gen-3

Comment: Please try passing `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=3` as a kernel boot option (try both). Also try `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` Please check this topic: https://superuser.com/questions/1509312/sound-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-linux-5-4-intel-hd-audio

Comment: @JaromandaX Alsamixer doesn't work, aumix doesn't work, etc, etc..

Comment: @Tashkinov None of those work. :(

Comment: `doesn't work etc etc` isn't exactly descriptive - can you elaborate. how about looking at system logs for example, there may be some useful information in them

Comment: Which logs _should_ I look at?

Comment: First install kernel 6.2.6, then file a bug report at bugzilla.kernel.org and attach ALSA info output: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh

Comment: @Tashiknov Kernel 6.2.6 isn't available for Debian 12 Bookworm...

Comment: OK. I got it working. I added ```options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1``` to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf